# Commenting on facebook using python script

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to comment on posts on facebook using the following python script:

```
import requests
import json
from time import strftime

AFTER = "1392891447"

TOKEN = 'access_token_here'

def get_posts():
    """Returns dictionary of id, first names of people who posted on my wall
    between start and end time"""

    query = ("SELECT post_id, actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE "
    "filter_key = 'others' AND source_id = me() AND "
    "created_time > " + AFTER + " LIMIT 200")

    payload = {'q': query, 'access_token': TOKEN}

    r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/fql', params=payload)

    result = json.loads(r.text)

    return result['data']

print get_posts()
def commentall(wallposts):
    """Comments thank you on all posts"""


    for wallpost in wallposts:
        r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/%s' %
        wallpost['actor_id'])
        url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/%s/comments' % wallpost['post_id']
        user = json.loads(r.text)
        message = 'Thanks %s :)' % user['first_name']
        payload = {'access_token': TOKEN, 'message': message}

        s = requests.post(url, data=payload)
        print s

        print "Wall post %s done" % wallpost['post_id']


commentall(get_posts())
```

I have added extra 'print s' to figure out what is happening.
This script when run gives output:

```
<Response[403] >
```

I am not able to figure out what the error is. I initially thought it was because of insufficient permissions to the token. I checked all the permission while obtaining token for graph explorer api. Still it doesn't work. The script prints the posts on my wall which were put within the given time frame.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

> """Returns dictionary of id, first names of people who posted on my
>   wall
>       between start and end time"""

I tested with filter_key = 'others' and found it was still contains my own post on my wall. So you can use actor_id!=me() instead:

> SELECT post_id, actor_id, filter_key, message FROM stream WHERE
>   actor_id!=me() AND source_id = me() AND created_time > 1392891447
>   LIMIT 200

Secondly, i recommend you to descrese **LIMIT** to 100 or 150, otherwise your request too hugh and may have high possibility to get timeout error.

Thirdly, both **print get_posts()** and commentall(**get_posts()**) is calling the stream API twice

Fourthly, **print "Wall post %s done" % wallpost['post_id']** is exception because **commentall(get_posts())** is not run yet.

Fifthly, please sleep some seconds before you try to comment on next post. Otherwise you are most likely to hit Graph API rate limit. This rate limit is in order to prevent people to spam.

Comment: I don't think I have an answer to my question. I have edited my question for fourth point. Why is it not working? Why am I not able to comment on the status?

Comment: Most likely you hit the rate limit. You can try to comment on single post first (break on enumerate index 1). You may hard code the post_id to test. If you still get the error, try to use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ to post the comments. I use your code and i have no problem to comment on the status.

Comment: is there a way to comment with a certain number of comments on a single post?Let's suppose I want to comment 10 comments in a row on a single post how can that be achieved?